# IN MYSQL how to pick up the largest count each row?

Tags: mysql, count, max

In mysql. I want to get some the largest counted review_id and mention.
below table is raw data

```
>> table Named: topic_id_review_id

   id       topic_id      review_id
+-------+-------------+-------------+
   1           1              1
   2           1              1
   3           1              1
   4           2              1
   5           4              1
   6           3              2
   7           5              2
   8           2              3
   9           2              3
  10           3              3
  11           3              1
  12           5              4
  13           5              1
  14           6              5
  16           7              7
  17           7              7
  18           7              7

...
....
```

**I want to get the top of four(4) topics about each of review_id.

```
>> wanted!!

    topic_id      review_id
+-------------+-------------+
      1              1
      2              1
      3              1
      4              1
      3              2
      5              2
      2              3
      3              3
      5              4
...
....

like above table, I want to top 4 topics in Every review_id.
```

I have already tried some code. but all of thing is not good results...

```
SELECT 
    tr1.topic_id, tr1.review_id 
    FROM topic_id_review_id tr1
    WHERE review_id IN (1,2,3)AND(
    SELECT COUNT(*)FROM topic_id_review_id tr2
    WHERE tr2.review_id = tr1.review_id) < 4;


SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM topic_id_review_id tr2
    WHERE tr2.review_id = 1
    GROUP BY topic_id, review_id
    order by `count` DESC LIMIT 4;
```

maybe your guy, this not difficult... but as beginner to me...
it is not simple. so please let me know to to solve it! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that works in all versions of MySql is the use of a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause which counts the number of `topic_id`s for each `review_id`:

```
select 
  t.topic_id, t.review_id
from (
  select min(id) id, topic_id, review_id
  from topic_id_review_id
  group by topic_id, review_id
) t
where (
  select count(*) from topic_id_review_id
  where review_id = t.review_id and topic_id <= t.topic_id and id < t.id
) <= 4
order by t.review_id, t.topic_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCqQpqTZSuW2ebByEPj1XT/0).
For **MySql 8.0+**:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    t.topic_id, t.review_id,
    row_number() over (partition by t.review_id order by t.topic_id, t.id) rn
  from (
    select min(id) id, topic_id, review_id
    from topic_id_review_id
    group by topic_id, review_id
  ) t  
)  
select 
  c.topic_id, c.review_id
from cte c
where c.rn <= 4
order by c.review_id, c.topic_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCqQpqTZSuW2ebByEPj1XT/1).
Results:

```
| topic_id | review_id |
| -------- | --------- |
| 1        | 1         |
| 2        | 1         |
| 3        | 1         |
| 4        | 1         |
| 3        | 2         |
| 5        | 2         |
| 2        | 3         |
| 3        | 3         |
| 5        | 4         |
| 6        | 5         |
| 7        | 7         |
```

Comment: oh sorry, mysql version is 8.0.12.
oh guys Thanks, this things really good for me. thanks!